# Can't execute mysql insert using pythons mysqldb

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

This is my first question on stackoverflow!
I'm currently programming a steamcommunity crawler, which crawls through the steam profiles and saves things like owned games, steamname, friends, ...
But when I try to run the insert command it just does NOTHING.

```
 if not self.check_user('games', id):
  print "insert"
  self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO games (userid) VALUES(%s);" % id)
```

The program displays "insert" but the execute command does neither throw an exception, nor inserts something to the database.
In addition, an eventualy happening exception is not caught. When I forexample change the query towards "INSERT INTO games (useridd)", the program quits and I see the exception.

The application is multithreaded but acquired before executing, so I can't see any issue in that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to [commit the transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/commit.html).

Answer (score 6):

1. add "COMMIT" at the end of command

   for example:

   ```
   cursor.execute("INSERT INTO games (userid) VALUES(%s);COMMIT;" % id)
   ```
2. set autocommit by add the second line

   ```
   db = MySQLdb.connect(user='username', db=dbName,) # exmaple
   db.autocommit(1) # enable auto commit
   ```
3. add commit() after transaction

   ```
   db.commit()
   ```